# Python Code executes, but result screen shows a long line of characters

Tags: org-mode, python

So my professor is obsessed with emacs and has encouraged us to set it up on our personal devices. Under his guidance I downloaded it, and he gave us some homework in a .org file. Inside this file, we use <s + TAB to start a code block. We then specify for the code block what language we are doing. So far, I can run R and SQL but Python has some issues. While we specify the language AND it is recognized since the syntax is recognized and the words changes colors etc... When I go to execute the file, this happens:

```
 #+begin_src python :python python3
     x = 1
     print(x)
   #+end_src

  #+RESULTS:
   : __PYTHON_EL_eval("try:\n    with open('/var/folders/jn/_v1gzqjj2wj_v1vs_6zmn3y40000gn/T/babel-UI3Hxa/python-2tLVuP') as __org_babel_python_tmpfile:\n        exec(compile(__org_babel_python_tmpfile.read(), __org_babel_python_tmpfile.name, 'exec'))\nexcept:\n    raise\nfinally:\n    print('
```

Comment: Can you try adding the header argument `:results output` to your code block? I don't know what's going on, but maybe that will throw some light.